# Generating Web.Config Transform File from existing spearate Web Config

Tags: web-config, web-config-transform

Is there a method/process that can take a web config file, i.e. WebConfigDev, and a second web config file, i.e. WebConfigQA, and generate a web config transform file for WebConfigDev to WebConfigQA?

I'm looking to have the files generated automatically because I currently have separate config files for each environment that I manually rename when deploying to a new environment. Each config file is fairly extensive and would require a fair amount of time to rework by hand and I'm hoping there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not an existing utility within Visual Studio 2010 to do this.